# Mobile site says "your answer couldn't.." when submitting a question edit that creates a new tag

Tags: bug, edits, mobile-web, tag-creation

Noticed this on Bicycles, but I presume it affects any Stack Exchange site

1. Write question
2. Edit question, write a new tag
3. Submit edit

When performing the above steps, I properly get an error message, but it says "answer" instead of "question" or "edit".

[image: Screenshot of submission form]

Comment: Time to charge your smartphone ;)

Comment: I stack all the way to 1%, just love the risk of losing my carefully crafted answers :)

Comment: This [also happens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305945/wrong-verbiage-in-error-alert-message-while-suggesting-edits?noredirect=1) for edits that don't go through for any reason, not just for creating tags without rep.