# Wrong verbiage in error alert message while suggesting edits

Tags: discussion, bug

I was suggesting an edit to a question, while submitting it says:

> Oops! Your answer couldn’t be submitted because:

Should this read as `Your edit suggestion couldn’t be submitted` or better verbiage?

[image]